# Old scifi tv series where a possessed astronaut tries to figure out a passcode

Tags: story-identification, tv

Trying to find name of the show and episode of an old (possibly black and white) sci-fi television show for my dad.

From what he can remember the episode is about a couple of astronauts on a planet and one of them leaves the spaceship/base and gets possessed. He comes back to get to attack the other astronaut but the combination to the lock has been changed. The episode ends with the possessed astronaut at the keypad trying every combination 0000, 0001, 0002, etc.

Sorry it's not much to go on, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you know if he saw this in the 50s or the 60s?

Comment: He can't remember when. He thinks it was black and white, but not positive on that.

Comment: The passcode sounds post 1980 -- most people only started to be familiar with passcodes I think with the advent of ATMs which was probably after 1982 or 1983 -- it was so  new that money could be removed multiple times from different locations because no network (i can't even think how that worked -- did they upload every account balance using a diskette every night? u could only use ATMs for your branch? or maybe they had a network but only a nightly batch job)

Comment: It sounds like an early Twilight Zone plot. They usually had a twist. Good luck!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Twilight_Zone_(1959_TV_series)_episodes

Comment: Could this have been a Gerry Anderson show? I remember something similar in either *Stingray* or *Captain Scarlet*.

Comment: @releseabe, I think the early bank cards had a magnetic strip that could record withdrawals. So, if you took your card to another machine, it would read that you had already withdrawn a certain amount that day. And there was a maximum daily withdrawal limit.

Comment: @pete: i am pretty sure that around 1983 it was possible to withdraw from multiple ATMs and if u only had 200, you could get out more. Now, if today the bank accidentally credits your account with a million bucks (extra) by accident and something like this has happened, spending is illegal and they will legally be able to get it back or you might go to jail for fraud. Same thing in 1983. I assume addressing the problem, perhaps as you describe, was a very high priority although the paucity of ATMs in those days mitigated the problem.

Comment: Not complete match, but Doctor Who: Harvest of Time has similar scene.

Answer (score 7):

I remember this one.  I think it's [Monsters S3E10, The Waiting Game](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0394799/), from 1990.

It isn't astronauts though, it's US Air Force officers inside a nuclear launch facility who live through a nuclear war only to be confronted with vampires who are now free to roam the world, safe under the dark skies of the apocalypse.

The ending scene is exactly as you describe it.

Full episode:
https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x6vuh1v